# UDPSocketClient.Receiveln doesn't Proceed all Incoming Data

Tags: delphi

I'm using Delphi XE4, with UDPSocketClient I send a Request to the Server.
The Request is successful, but the responce from the Server is always about 200 bytes.
It should be about 1000 bytes.

I have no clue why?! There is no EOL break or something like that.

Is it possible to read in Chunks?

```
procedure TForm1.SendCommand(const Pass, ACommand: string);
var
 Cmd: string;

begin
  if UDPSocketClient.Connected then
  begin
    Cmd := Pass + ' ' + ACommand;
    UDPSocketClient.Sendln(AnsiString(Cmd));
    Memo1.Lines.Add('');
    Memo1.Lines.Add('######################');
    Memo1.Lines.Add(ACommand);
    Memo1.Lines.Add('######################');
    Memo1.Lines.Add('');
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.BtnSendCmdClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Buff: AnsiString;
  received: string;
begin

  if Assigned(CurrentServer) and (CmdEdit.Text <> '') and
    (CmdEdit.Text <> CmdEditPlaceHolder) then
  begin
    SendCommand(CurrentServer.Password, CmdEdit.Text);
  end;
  try
   received := String(UDPSocketClient.Receiveln(Buff));
   Memo1.Lines.Add(received);
    finally
     CmdEdit.SetFocus;
end;
```

Comment: Can you show the server code? Probably the server is sending multiple datagrams.. Also, your code looks like its missing a `begin...end;` around the tx/rx bits

Comment: sry, fixed the code, lost at copy and paste. the server sends a string which is about 1000 bytes with spaces in between. Doesn't have the source for server.

Comment: So you're trying to receive even if you don't send anything..? Seems odd.

Comment: SendCommand(CurrentServer.Password, CmdEdit.Text); this is what i send to the server. after that i receive the answer

Comment: but you've now got a weird `end;begin` in the middle of your code. So the second (receive) block runs even if the conditional fails.

Comment: The password you send is not the password you pass to the function that sends data. Are you sure you're not getting the "authentication failed" response instead of the response you expect?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using TUDPSocket.

The parameter for `ReceiveLn` is the [delimiter string to search for](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/2010/en/Sockets.TBaseSocket.Receiveln). You're passing it `Buff` which is an empty string, so the behaviour is likely to be undefined.

Comment: Do you have an example for me how I can implement it?

Comment: @JanW. Just leave out `Buff`. the default is a newline sequence.

Comment: It doesnt work. I can only Receive about 200byte, wenn the data length reached more than 200byte there will be nothing displayed in the memo. I guess the SocketBuffer is managed by TUDPSocket itself. Isn't it possible to read the complete Socket Buffer as TStringlist?

Comment: If i try to write the received string direct to an assigned File, the same Problem appears.

Comment: Jan, are you sure you are passing a correct password as [`Rob pointed out`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746112/udpsocketclient-receiveln-doesnt-proceed-all-incoming-data#comment31088095_20746112) ? You are concatenating `Pass` variable, not `RconPass` parameter value...

Comment: Yes i am sure, i edit the source above. my aource is definetly correct. if i look with wireshark, the pakets are received correct, but i think they get lost anywhere in the socketbuffer. and i have no clue why.

Answer (score 0):

So, now I have an approach to a solution.

When i send the Command to the Server, there are two possibilitys to receive the Data:

1. The Incoming UDP Package is less than 200bytes, everything will be correct.
2. If the Incoming UDP Package reached the 1.3kb, then there are two udp packages in the socket buffer. But i can't get the Packages to my Application.